# How to calculate size for assets in UWP/Windows Phone Scale folders

Tags: uwp, windows-10-mobile

Actually, I matched my images size to Nokia Lumia 830 ( Scale-160) and i want to made my interface looks good on another devices ( in another scale mode ). In android i got documentation where all size image in folder assets is defined ( ldpi is 1x, mdi 1,5 x, etc) and i looking for some similar information about windows phone or ready tools that re-calculate size for me ( like android drawable tools in Android Studio).

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to read about UWP Design. Take a look at these:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/layout/design-and-ui-intro

Take in mind effective pixels it's not the same that pixels size, that should be your starter point. Then, use properly the layouts and the adaptive triggers. These main concepts should make your app work at any screen size.

> When your app runs on a device, the system uses an algorithm to normalize the way UI elements display on the screen. This scaling algorithm takes into account viewing distance and screen density (pixels per inch) to optimize for perceived size (rather than physical size). The scaling algorithm ensures that a 24 px font on Surface Hub 10 feet away is just as legible to the user as a 24 px font on 5' phone that's a few inches away.